# Change TYPO3 content to templavoila

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I want to use templavoila on an existing website. So i have to link all the regular content in the templavoila Page Module. I dont want to do this by hand as there are multiple thousand entrys.
I looked up how TV saved those entries and they just have a Flexform field in the database with an xml where i can list the UIDs of the content elements - simple.

But now i want to get the elements and i can select them via PID so i have the right content elements for the actual page. So far so good, but in the old module there are two columns (content and right) and i have no idea how to decide in which column a contentelement is.
Is there a column in the tt_content table that i did not see or is this done somehow else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok due to a mistake i did not see it for the rows that i looked up. The column is called "calPos" and if value = 2 then it is the right one, otherwise the content. Simple.